# A communication error occurred: "Can't send more" when upload file in laravel 5.8

Tags: laravel-5.8

I am trying to upload 2MB file but i still get :

> "Network Error (tcp_error)
>
> A communication error occurred: "Can't send more" The Web Server may be down, too busy, or experiencing other problems preventing it from responding to requests. You may wish to try again at a later time.
>
> For assistance, contact your network support team."

I changed PHP settings to increase upload `size`, `max_post_size`, and `max_execution_time`, but it doesn't work.